# Split scanner input and typecast into array of strings

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use Java to solve a simple challenge but I have unsuccessful and I can't find an answer. The idea is that the user enters a string of text, and the program returns the longest word in that string. I can use Scanner to accept the input from the user, and then the .split() method to split the string at the spaces with `.split(" ")` but I can't figure out how to store the split sentence in an array that I can iterate through to find the longest word. I always get a console output that looks like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@401a7a05
```

I have commented out the code that I think should find the longest word so as to focus on the problem of being unable to use Scanner input to create an array of Strings. My code at the moment is:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class longestWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int longest = 0;
        String word = null;
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter string of text: ");
        String b = n.nextLine();
        String c[] = b.split(" ");

        //for (int i = 0; i <= b.length(); i++) {
        //    if (longest < b[i].length()) {
        //  longest = b[i].length();
        //  word = b[i];
        //    }
        //}
        //System.out.println(word);

        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are iterating over the string, not the array, and trying to output the entire array. Change your for loop to use `c` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) //In an array, length is a property, not a function
{
    if (longest < c[i].length())
    {
        longest = c[i].length();
        word = c[i];
    }
}
```

That should fix your first output. Then you want to change how you output your array, change that to something like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Which will display the array like so:

```
[word1, word2, word3, word4]
```

So you want to get the input as a string and automatically make it an array? You can do that simply by calling the `split` function after `nextLine` on the scanner:

```
String[] wordArray = n.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I need the code to do is if the user enters the string "where are the greenmoonmen", then the code would use accept the input with Scanner and then split the string into an array of ["where", "are", "the", "greenmoonmen"] so that I could iterate through that array. So how do I accept input with Scanner as a String and then typecast the string into an array?

Answer (score 0):

there are many mistakes in you code. such a

you were

- iterating over string not on array.
- `if (longest < b[i].length())` as b is your string not array of string

try this it will work it will print the longest word and its size as well. 
    class Test {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int longest = 0;
        String word = null;
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter string of text: ");
        String b = n.nextLine();
        String c[] = b.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (longest < c[i].length()) {
          longest = c[i].length();
          word = c[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(word);

        System.out.println(longest);
    }
}
```